# General solution of $(u.u_{xy}) - (u_x.u_y) = 0$

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

$(u.u_{xy}) - (u_x.u_y) = 0$

I'm in bad need to answer this question. Please help.

I considered $D= (d/dx)$ & $D'= (d/dy)$
so I came to $(U^2)DD'-(U^2)DD'=0$
but its already obvious that these terms are equal. I don't know what to do to get the general solution

Comment: Can you share what you've tried? What are some tools you know for solving PDE's? Where are you getting stuck? Please [edit] your post to include your thoughts and efforts.

Comment: Wat do u mean by * ?

Comment: @user107676 just a product

Comment: I wrote what I did

Comment: Then, tell us what you have tried so far and the idea you have on this topic@user118592

Comment: it's written above

Comment: Whoopsiedoodle!  Once again, due to the ungainly proximity of buttons on my 'droid, I have accidentally posted my answer somewhat prematurely.  Thus I (temporarily) deleted it while I finish it off.  Should be posted soon . . . right, we've heard that one before.  Anyway, sorry about any confusion, and *staaaaay tuuuuuned*!

Comment: Notice that 

$$ \frac{u_{xy}}{u_x} = \frac{u_y}{u}$$

is

$$ \partial_y  \log u_x = \partial_y \log(u)$$

solve, and apply the trick again, but with respect to $x$.

As long as $u_x > 0$ and $u > 0$, this makes sense. It also hints towards the full solution.

Answer (score 2):

The general solution is:
$$ u(x,y)=F(x)\cdot G(y)$$ where $F$ and $G$ are arbitrary functions.

Comment: How to apply this?

Comment: This is the general solution as given on p.287 of *Handbook of Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations*, Polynanin & Zaitsev, 2004.

Comment: But I don't have a given function to derive Uxy , Ux or Uy ??

Comment: can any one explain how to get F(x) and G(y) in this formula ?

Comment: The general solution of a PDE often has undetermined constants or undetermined functions. To get F(x) and G(y) would require additional information, such as boundary conditions, initial conditions, etc. (Which type of initial data you have depends on the application & also on the equation.)

Comment: in this prob. I have no conditions .. but let it be for example 

U(0,y)=j(y) & U(0,y)=l(y) 

so what is the sequences ?

Comment: Certain types of initial data work for certain equations... I don't know if U(0,y)=j(y) & U(0,y)=l(y) would work for this PDE. This PDE is an example of a nonlinear wave equation (this can be seen via the transformation $x = (r+s)/2$ and $y = (r-s)/2$, which yields the PDE $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2} - \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial s^2} + \left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial s} \right) \left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial s} \right) = 0$) -- I can't help because I do not know the theory of nonlinear wave equations.

Comment: @Kyle:  not to put too fine a point on it, but it's *Polyanin*, not *Polynanin*.  And what a marvelous compendium that book is!

Answer (score 0):

I have completely deleted this answer and started over since I somehow by accident hit the CW button and don't know how to reverse the effect.  Sorry for any confusion.